# Change the shape of a circle image to an oval shape using Java in Android

Tags: java, android, image-scaling

Circle image is, for example, a cup or a plate

**What needs to be done** - An oval shape of the same circle image

The image itself transforms into an oval, and not just the outer shape

Comment: Simply stretch the width or the height. Not being equal, the circle becomes an oval.

Comment: I am  done actually...thanks